# lftp mirror directory and all its subdirectories

Tags: backup, mirror, lftp

Here's my problem I'm having. I want to download or "backup" a folder with a bunch of other folders in it using LFTP. My folder hierarchy looks like this.

```
Documents 
-Music
--Unknown_artist 
---Unknown_CD
-Pictures
--summer_pics
--Denver
---Brewery
---Foot_ball_game
```

So i want to download or backup the Documents directory and all its components. I am restricted by only using strictly FTP.

I love using LFTP because of its pget command.

```
@#> lftp server.com -u username,pass -e 'mirror Documents --use-pget-n=16 && exit'
```

This works but it only downloads the Documents directory and non of its sub directories. 
Now i can manually go into each directory and download them that way, but there has to be a flag im missing or something im not reading right in the documentation.

In the documentation i saw that there was a "mirror -r" flag that states "don't go into subdirectories" So i should be downloading subdirectories without the "-r" right?

I figured it out ..

The answer is

```
@#> lftp server.com -u username,pass -e 'glob -d mirror Documents --use-pget-n=16 && exit'
```

Comment: For me simple 'mirror Documents' works. It downloads subdirectories, but just doesn't create Documents dir.